# Convert milliseconds since midnight into a time object

Tags: c++, time

I have an incoming data feed that gives me an int with the number of milliseconds since midnight.

I'd like to convert it into some sort of time object so I can display the time.

For example, 1000 = 00:00:01

Is there a simple way to do this?  Do I need a time struct?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need anything specific? AM/PM or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ms / 1000
seconds = x % 60
x /= 60
minutes = x % 60
x /= 60
hours = x % 24
```

Then you can `cout` the time that has been parsed for you. This is only for duration since midnight. It won't show you the date.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a little helper struct for this, but this could be a little bit to much for your simple request:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>    

struct MidnightTime{
    MidnightTime(unsigned int miliseconds) : 
    seconds((miliseconds/1000) % 60), 
    minutes((miliseconds/60000) % 60),
    hours((miliseconds/3600000) % 24){}

    unsigned int seconds, minutes, hours;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MidnightTime& t){
    out << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << t.hours << ":" <<
           std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << t.minutes << ":" << 
           std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << t.seconds;
    return out;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << MidnightTime(1000) << std::endl; // will result in 00:00:01
    return 0;
}
```